# Is there a name for this measure of sequence "monotonicity"?

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, monotone-functions

Say I have a sequence, $a=(1,2,3,4,3,6,7)$. It is obviously not a monotonic sequence. It would be monotonic though if the 5th value would be at least $4$. I would like to say that the sequence is not monotonic by $1$. In other words the sequence' "non-monotonicity" is 1.

Consider the following sequences with their respective "non-monotonicity"

$b=(1,3,-5,9,2),$ $nm(b)=8+7=15$

$c=(2,0,2,0,2),$ $nm(c)=2+2=4$

$d=(1,3,-5,0,2),$ $nm(c)=8+3+1=12$

The above "non-monotonicity" is only defined for increasing sequences, so we could call it "increasing non-monotonicity", and similarly define a decreasing non-monotonicity.

I am curious if such a concept is already properly defined for sequences and perhaps for functions as well, because I would like to read more about it and how it could be used.